# ADFS Single Logout fails with Requester status code

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, onelogin, adfs3.0

Trying to integrate a SAML service provider application with AD FS. SSO works fine. For SLO the logout fails with 'Requester' status code. There's no logging/tracing information from the event viewer for ADFS service for this specific error. The question had been asked several times before, most of them point to an invalid `NameId` sent in `LogoutRequest`. However, the `LogoutRequest NameId` seems alright.
Also tried storing the session index and send as `SessionIndex`, but the error was the same.
Here're the relevant messages

`AssertionResponse Subject`

```
<Subject>
       <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">alice@mail2.corp2.contoso.net</NameID>
       <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_43372d41-c455-4322-970a-db4c1acf73bc"
                NotOnOrAfter="2021-03-03T09:41:58.596Z" Recipient="https://myapp.corp2.dev.net:8050/saml2/adfs/acs"/></SubjectConfirmation>
</Subject>
```

`LogoutRequest`

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest Destination="https://adfs.corp2.contoso.net/adfs/ls/"
    ID="_5bcedc5e-8847-41c6-95b3-29740f0463ec" IssueInstant="2021-03-03T09:37:03Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>https://myapp.corp2.dev.net:8050/saml2/adfs/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">alice@mail2.corp2.contoso.net</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

`LogoutResponse`

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse ID="_85f5200f-179a-40f8-a139-97c482cf2900"
        Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-03-03T09:37:03.314Z"
        Destination="https://myapp.corp2.dev.net:8050/saml2/adfs/logout"
        Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
        InResponseTo="_5bcedc5e-8847-41c6-95b3-29740f0463ec"
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                http://adfs.corp2.contoso.net/adfs/services/trust
        </Issuer>
        <samlp:Status>
                <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
        </samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

- Can anyone guide as to what could be wrong here?
- ADFS Logs/Debug traces don't have anything on the error. ADFS is a 2012 R2 Datacenter edition. Anyone aware of any updates/patches on a later version (say, Server 2016) that could have resolved similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

Your `NameID` is still missing other attributes ADFS requires in logout requests.

In particular, you miss

- `SPNameQualifier`
- `NameQualifier`
- `SPProvidedID`
- `SessionIndex`

All have to be retrieved from the assertion that comes to your SP upon authentication and then copied to the logout request (consult the `LogoutRequest` model to find out where to put them).

Technically you can store them as additional claims or properties of the name claim you create at your SP.

**Edit 1**, doublechecked these. Though I have only ADFS2 at hand (which should not be a problem since SAML2 support is there, too).

The `SPProvidedID` is not there in the assertion in the first place so it's not in the logout request. Other attributes are there. The signature is also there, note that according to the specs, logout requests have to be signed. Make sure signature's hash algorithm matches the one you set up in ADFS.

An example logout request that is accepted by ADFS:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
                     xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
                     xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                     ID="_g9b2ba1ab-78c0-409e-a009-3fe4941072e2" 
                     Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-03-04T08:48:24.198609Z" 
                     Destination="https://adfs.odev1.local/adfs/ls/" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>https://localhost:44307/Account/Logon</saml:Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#_g9b2ba1ab-78c0-409e-a009-3fe4941072e2">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>VuQ...=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>XFO/...==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" 
                 SPNameQualifier="https://localhost:44307/Account/Logon" 
                 NameQualifier="https://adfs.odev1.local/adfs/ls">DEV1\wiktor</saml:NameID>
    <samlp:SessionIndex>_cb98e9ca-b3b9-46cb-a30a-5a6980d8703e</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Comment: As per saml core 2.0 standard, `SPNameQualifier`, `NameQualifier` and `SPProvidedID`  and `SessionIndex` are all optional. The first 3 attributes are also not set in the assertion response. Also, I tried setting `SessionIndex`, but doesn't help

Comment: They are optional but somehow signing out doesn't work without setting these. Spent hours trying to make that working like two years ago. I wonder however why all three are not present in your response, it was there when we tested it. I'll take a look at it. Make sure twice your session id is correct in login response.

Comment: Afaik, ADFS prefers the NameId in the way it was sent in the assertion response. It depends on your ADFS configuration what attributes are sent out. In my case, it's only `NameId` with `Format` and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, indeed, ADFS only accepts LogoutRequest's NameID if it repeats all all attributes sent eariler in an assertion. Spent few minutes trying to find where it can be changed and  failed. It just works for us. Are your requests signed? (your question misses this detail)

Comment: Yes, they are always signed, rsa-sha256

Comment: Have you checked adfs log section in the system event log? It should contain more info on the issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, nothing in logs and debug traces. I believe signing is not the issue here, as we will see event log errors with SIgnature verification failures.